# Unable to resolve class in build.gradle using Android Studio 0.60/Gradle 0.11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Established app working fine using **Android Studio 0.5.9**/ **Gradle 0.9** but upgrading to **Android Studio 0.6.0**/ **Gradle 0.11** causes the error below.

Somehow Studio seems to have lost the ability to resolve the android tools import at the top of the build.gradle file.

Anyone got any ideas on how to solve this?

```
build file 'Users/[me]/Repositories/[project]/[module]/build.gradle': 1: unable to resolve class com.android.builder.DefaultManifestParser @ line 1, column 1.
import com.android.builder.DefaultManifestParser 
1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:858)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:548)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:497)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:306)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:287)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:115)
... 77 more
2014-06-09 10:15:28,537 [  92905]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at '/Users/[me]/Repositories/[project]'
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:53)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
```

**[project]/[module]/build.gradle**

```
import com.android.builder.DefaultManifestParser

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'android'

android {

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
        debug {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']
        }
        release {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/release/res']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                def file = variant.outputFile
                def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser()
                def wmgVersionCode = manifestParser.getVersionCode(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
                println wmgVersionCode
                variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace("-release.apk", "_" + wmgVersionCode + ".apk"))
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}



def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = file('signing.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()){
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props!=null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
            props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {

        println 'RELEASE BUILD SIGNING'

        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
    } else {
        println 'RELEASE BUILD NOT FOUND SIGNING PROPERTIES'

        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
}else {
    println 'RELEASE BUILD NOT FOUND SIGNING FILE'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.changeloglib:library:1.4.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.+'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.11'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.11'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.11'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:security:0.1.+'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'uk.co.androidalliance:edgeeffectoverride:1.0.1+'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1+'
    compile project(':captureActivity')
    compile ('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.+') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/CWAC-LoaderEx.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Been having the same problem as you all day, turns out it just moved package!

Change:

```
import com.android.builder.DefaultManifestParser
```

To:

```
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser
```

Works for me now! :)

Comment: Good spotting. I'll put that down to a combination of me being unobservant and the Great Goog continuing their fine tradition of changing stuff out from under developers. Again. :/